# Java: how to open new jframe UNDER the parent window

Tags: java, popup, z-index

How would i go about creating and opening a new jframe UNDER the parent frame. Im trying to achieve an effect where the new window (undecorated) appears to slide out from behind the parent window. Right now it opens in focus, losing the effect.

Comment: Why do you want to create another JFrame under parent JFrame create JDialogue instead by using modality feature.

Comment: it doesnt quite fit the effect that im trying to achieve. i figured it out though. kind of clunky, but i just instantiate the window and immediately have the parent window request focus.

Comment: What if the first window is actually a non-modal JDialog and the parent window is the one you want under it, that is initially invisible, then made visible.  The JDialog has to stay on top of the parent window.

Answer (score 0):

(J)Frame has no parent. It does have `GraphicsConfiguration` though but I guess you aint asking that.
If you want to get back the focus to the opener window. Something in this line shall do:

```
 final JFrame parent = ...
 JFrame f=new JFrame();
 f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
     @Override
     public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
         e.getWindow().removeWindowListener(this);//do not listen any more, we do
         EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){//wait for the pending events
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                         parent.toFront();
                     }                          
                 });
             }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Write following inside constructor of child/popup jframe

```
setModal(true);
```